# Join object values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this object:

```
"cuisines":{
  "2": "Burgers",
  "7": "American",
  "9": "Sandwiches",
  "11": "Breakfast"
}
```

How i can transform it to be like this?

```
Burgers, American, Sandwiches, Breakfast
```

I'm using angular.

Comment: Loop through it to get these values?

Comment: What? Transform it to a comma separated string?

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.forEach this docs is irrefragable answer.

Comment: Lol, how many answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't why you want it but you can try this,

```
var cuisine = {
  "2": "Burgers",
  "7": "American",
  "9": "Sandwiches",
  "11": "Breakfast"
};
var data =[];
$.each(cuisine, function(key,val){
    data.push(val);
});

console.log(data.join(','));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/guTb2/)

Comment: Thanks, nice and clear solution!

Answer (score 1):

As the order of properties in an object is not guaranteed, you would have to sort the properties to get them in that order. Put them in an array and sort them, then you can put the names in an array and join it:

```
var o = {
  "2": "Burgers",
  "7": "American",
  "9": "Sandwiches",
  "11": "Breakfast"
};

var arr = [];
for (key in o) {
    arr.push({ key: key, value: o[key] });
}
arr.sort(function(x,y){ return x.key - y.key});
var names = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    names.push(arr[i].value);
}
var result = names.join(', ');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/6HkNE/

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very strange question and one that doesn't really have anything to do with Angular itself.  It seems like a purely javascript question.

That being said, you should be able to do this:

```
var values = [];
for(var key in cuisines){
    if(cuisines.hasOwnProperty(key)){
         values.push(cuisines[key]);
    }
}
// values now looks like ["Burgers","American","Sandwiches","Breakfast"]
```